# is there a way to setup a listener for a Telegram Bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, webhooks, telegram-webhook

I would like to listen to a Telegram Bot message -the Bot is sort of a weather Bot, and on every new message, I want to get that message- in a programmatic way.

I tried to use another Bot but Telegram doesn't allow interaction Bot-to-Bot!

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You'll need to create your own Telegram library to do this.

Comment: Could you elaborate? @0stone0

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment to an answer as OP requested to eleborate it.

---

> I would like to listen to a Telegram Bot message in a programmatic way

This is not possible using the Telegram Bot Api. As you already mentioned, Bot-to-Bot interaction is impossible at this point.

---

Of course, there are a few ways of achieving your desired outcome, I'll mention 2 of them:

1. Alter the bot you want listen to, let the Bot trigger a custom endpoint/script that will fit your needs
2. Using the official [Telegram TDLib API](https://core.telegram.org/api#tdlib--build-your-own-telegram), you can create your [own Telegram Application](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id), this way, you can programmicaly preform any action that a regular Client might do, this include 'listening' to messages from Bots and triggering any kind of webhook to fit your needs

Comment: Thank you, But I forgot to mention that the Bot I wanted to listen to isn't mine! it's sort of a weather Bot, and on every new message I want to get that message